# Why is my Navigation drawer menu opens other activities automatically without clicking the buttons?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

What i have is left navigation menu that i have made using navigation drawer and i want it's button to open activities instead of fragments .. but the weird thing is that when the main activity opens which has the menu it open the second activity direct without displaying the main activity .. here is my code :

```
private void displayView(int position) {

    Intent intent = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gallery.class);
        break;
     ....
    if(intent != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        // error in creating activity
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating Activity");
    }
}
```

And i call it from here :

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }
```

So why this is happening? can anyone help me?

Comment: *it open the second activity direct without displaying the main activity* - are you sure you aren't triggering the navigation item click listener when starting the activity?

Comment: what do you mean by this?? this menu was working just fine with fragments but with activities it didn't work . i have no idea why !!

Comment: In generally there is some setup done for the navigation drawer when the activity holding it starts. If in that code you were doing something that triggers `displayView()` then obviously the other activity will start. Check from where you call that method.

Comment: mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   // on first time display view for first nav item
   displayView(0);
  }

Comment: i have edit my answer .. see it please

Comment: please make your comment as an answer so i can vote it :))

Comment: See this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039147/close-navigation-drawer-on-application-start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In generally, the navigation drawer is initialized with some code when the activity starts(to show one of the items/do something). If, when you start the activity holding this navigation drawer, you immediately go the one of the activities pointed by the navigation drawer items then you need to check your code to see if you're not by any chance calling the `displayView()` method when the activity starts(which will start the other activity).

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented a ListView inside of your Navigation Drawer? I had the same problem and it turns out that when I was setting my adapter for the ListView I was using

```
    divListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item__activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            divisionAda));
```

The ListView was "activated" making it gain focus and displaying it on top of the activity. I remedied the problem by removing the "activated".

So now my setting my adapter looks like this:

```
    divListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            divisionAda));
```