# Close Navigation Drawer on application start

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have developed an application with Navigation Drawer. Whenever the application starts for the first time, it has navigation drawer open.

Is there any way I can set it as closed? Below is the auto generated code for your understanding.

```
import com.example.navigationdrawer.R;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; import android.app.Activity; import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle; import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat; import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout; import android.content.SharedPreferences; import android.content.res.Configuration; import android.os.Bundle; import android.preference.PreferenceManager; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.Menu; import android.view.MenuInflater; import android.view.MenuItem; import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.AdapterView; import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.ListView; import android.widget.Toast;

/**  * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation  * drawer. See the <a href=  * "https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction"
* > design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors  * implemented here.  */ public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**      * Remember the position of the selected item.   */     private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**      * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the     * user manually expands it. This shared preference tracks this.     */     private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**      * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).  
*/  private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**      * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.   */     private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;     private ListView mDrawerListView;   private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;   private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {     }

    @Override   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated         // awareness of the         // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {           mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);           mFromSavedInstanceState = true;         }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
            }

    @Override   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of       // actions in the action bar.       setHasOptionsMenu(true);    }

    @Override   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,          Bundle savedInstanceState) {        mDrawerListView
= (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
                mDrawerListView
                .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        selectItem(position);
                    }
                });         mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
                .getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),

                }));        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);

        return mDrawerListView;     }


    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {         return mDrawerLayout != null
                && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);  }

    /**      * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation     * drawer interactions.      *   * @param fragmentId     *      The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.    * @param drawerLayout   *            The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.    */     public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {      mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer       // opens        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);       // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();       actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);      actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions      // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.       mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), /* host Activity */        mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */        R.drawable.custom_ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */       R.string.navigation_drawer_open, /*
                                         * "open drawer" description for
                                         * accessibility
                                         */         R.string.navigation_drawer_close /*
                                         * "close drawer" description for
                                         * accessibility
                                         */         ) {             @Override           public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()           }

            @Override           public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to
                    // prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true)
                            .commit();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()           }       };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce      // them to the drawer,      // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.         if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {          mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);       }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.      mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {             @Override           public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();          }       });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);     }

    private void selectItem(int position) {         mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;        if (mDrawerListView != null) {          mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);         }       if (mDrawerLayout != null) {            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);      }       if (mCallbacks != null) {           mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);        }   }

    @Override   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {       super.onAttach(activity);       try {           mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;      } catch (ClassCastException e) {            throw new ClassCastException(
                    "Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");      }   }

    @Override   public void onDetach() {        super.onDetach();       mCallbacks
= null;     }

    @Override   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);     }

    @Override   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.       mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);    }

    @Override   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {         // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar.        // See also         // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the      // action bar.      if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {          inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);          showGlobalContextActionBar();       }       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);  }

    @Override   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {            return true;        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();            return true;        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);   }

    /**      * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to    * show the global app 'context', rather than just what's in the current     * screen.   */     private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {         ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();       actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);         actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.selectStr);     }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {      return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();   }

    /**      * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must      * implement.    */     public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {         /**          * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.         */         void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);  } }
```

Comment: Please post the code relevant to your navigation drawer. The default implementation provided by Google will show the navigation drawer when the app launches until the user proves that they have learned of its existence by opening the drawer once.

Comment: Hi Tanis, 
it's the auto generated code. Let me share here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a

```
mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);
```

change that code to the one of the followings

```
mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
```

or

```
mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true);
```

Or you can remove completely the logic of checking if the drawer is opened or not at the first time when the app runs and the related code to it (mUserLearnedDrawer variable and so on)

```
 if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to
                    // prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true)
                            .commit();
                }
```

Comment: @user3065901I think it is just a constant for preferences. You can use any string value.